# JavaFX FXML doesn't see my controller methods correctly "Controller is not defined on root component" when using fxml as component within fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm creating rich ui application and I use FXML within FXML and every part have separate controllers. I decided to follow [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/creating-custom-javafx) tutorial and use my fxml as component. So I use class as a controller and component. Everything seems to be working but I hit a wall when I try to put methods into my class/controller. I edited my FXML so I don't put controller directly into it. But using class itself. this is where the problematic line is

```
<fx:root fx:id="profilePane" onMouseClicked="#select" onMouseEntered="#hoverOver" onMouseExited="#hoverOut" type="javafx.scene.layout.Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">...etc
```

every method is red saying that **Controller is not defined on root component** well I know that I removed that part from my fxml. But how would it work on tutorial that I follow? Here is my component class what I work with

```
imports etc..
public class FxmlProfilePanel extends Pane implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private ToggleButton toggleButton;

    @FXML
    private Pane profilePane;

    private FadeTransition fadeTransition=new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(500),toggleButton);


    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO


        System.out.println("Is fx thread?:"+Platform.isFxApplicationThread());
    }   

    public FxmlProfilePanel(){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/bitcompile/ecps/fxml/FxmlProfilePanel.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FxmlProfilePanel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    public void hoverOver(MouseEvent event){
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if(!toggleButton.isSelected()){
            toggleButton.setText("Select profile");
            fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
            fadeTransition.setToValue(1.0);
            fadeTransition.play();

            }else{
            toggleButton.setText("Deselect profile");
            fadeTransition.setFromValue(0);
            fadeTransition.setToValue(1.0);
            fadeTransition.play();
            }
        });
    }

      public void hoverOut(MouseEvent event){
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            if(toggleButton.isSelected())
            fadeTransition.setFromValue(1.0);
            fadeTransition.setToValue(0);
            fadeTransition.play();
        });
    }

    public void selected(MouseEvent event){
        if(!toggleButton.isSelected()){
          toggleButton.setSelected(true);
          toggleButton.setText("Profile Selected");

        }else{
            toggleButton.setSelected(false);
            toggleButton.setText("Select profile");
        }
    }
}
```

So question is.**When I use fxml/controller as component inside another fxml which is within another fxml etc. how do I connect my methods from within my component class?** (I know how to do all this following normal fxml style with separate controller etc, but not this way).. Did I pick the wrong way of doing this? Should I consider another approach? thx for any insight.

full fxml code:

```
<fx:root fx:id="profilePane" onMouseClicked="#select" onMouseEntered="#hoverOver" onMouseExited="#hoverOut" type="javafx.scene.layout.Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children><AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="384.0" prefWidth="270.0" style="-fx-border-color: #40464A;">
<children>
<StackPane prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="270.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
<children>
<Pane prefWidth="270.0">
<children><ImageView fitHeight="288.0" fitWidth="270.0" layoutY="49.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../resources/images/category/TechnologyTemp.png" />
</image>
<StackPane.margin>
<Insets top="45.0" />
</StackPane.margin>
<viewport>
<Rectangle2D />
</viewport></ImageView>
</children>
</Pane><BorderPane layoutX="79.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="258.0" prefWidth="270.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
<top>
<Pane prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
<children><VBox prefHeight="143.0" prefWidth="270.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
<children><Label text="Adobe">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
</font>
<padding>
<Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
</padding>
</Label><Label text="Adobe Systems,inc">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
</font>
<padding>
<Insets bottom="3.0" left="10.0" />
</padding>
</Label>
<Pane layoutX="-1.0" opacity="0.82" prefHeight="82.0" prefWidth="220.0">
<children><TextArea cache="true" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" mouseTransparent="true" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="82.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 0;" text="Oracle continually applies good corporate governance principles. The composition and activities of the company's Board of Directors, the approach to public disclosure" wrapText="true">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets top="53.0" />
</VBox.margin></TextArea>
</children>
</Pane>
</children></VBox>
</children>
</Pane>
</top>
<bottom>
<Pane prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="270.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
<children><VBox prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="270.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
<children><Label text="Technology">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
</font>
<padding>
<Insets left="10.0" top="4.0" />
</padding>
</Label><Label text="Software services &amp; provider">
<padding>
<Insets left="10.0" />
</padding>
<font>
<Font size="13.0" />
</font></Label>
</children></VBox>
</children>
</Pane>
</bottom></BorderPane>
</children>
</StackPane><Pane prefHeight="382.0" prefWidth="270.0">
<children><ToggleButton fx:id="toggleButton" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="191.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 0; -fx-background-color: #57A1DE;" text="Select profile" textFill="WHITE">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
</font></ToggleButton>
</children></Pane>
</children></AnchorPane>
</children>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: Is `<fx:root ...>` the root element of your FMXL file? I think that's the only place it is valid.

Comment: @James_D Yes thats the root element then children goes bellow it.So far whole ui is decoupled.This component shoud work by iself without any dependencies,hence thats why i made it as component.Bud i cant make those methods work no matter what i try.

Comment: So where are the errors? Are they compile errors in the Java code?

Comment: exactly on the line i posted fx:root.. etc each method is market as red and when i hover over error is saying -Controller is not defined on root component.Bud every single method exists in my class and also fx:root is a root element.I will post whole fxml in addition to my question

Comment: So it's just the IDE reporting the error, and it's in the FXML file, if I understand you correctly. Have you tried to see if it works anyway, since FXML isn't compiled?

Comment: Yes thats correct.No i didnt tryed it yet, i seen this as a red flag and didnt proceed bud i will give it a shot and report in shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works quite well with:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LoadOwnFXML extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {


            Scene scene = new Scene(new ProfilPane());
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And the ProfilePane class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class ProfilPane extends AnchorPane {

    public ProfilPane() {
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("my.fxml"));
            loader.setRoot(this);
            loader.setController(this);
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProfilPane.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void select() {
        System.out.println("selected");
    }

    @FXML
    public void hoverOver() {
        System.out.println("hovered");
    }

    @FXML
    public void hoverOut() {
        System.out.println("hovered out");
    }
}
```

The FXML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<fx:root fx:id="profilePane" onMouseClicked="#select" onMouseEntered="#hoverOver" onMouseExited="#hoverOut" type="javafx.scene.layout.Pane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
<children><AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="384.0" prefWidth="270.0" style="-fx-border-color: #40464A;">
<children>
<StackPane prefHeight="430.0" prefWidth="270.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
<children>
<Pane prefWidth="270.0">
<children><ImageView fitHeight="288.0" fitWidth="270.0" layoutY="49.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
<image>
<Image url="@../resources/images/category/TechnologyTemp.png" />
</image>
<StackPane.margin>
<Insets top="45.0" />
</StackPane.margin>
<viewport>
<Rectangle2D />
</viewport></ImageView>
</children>
</Pane><BorderPane layoutX="79.0" layoutY="100.0" prefHeight="258.0" prefWidth="270.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
<top>
<Pane prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
<children><VBox prefHeight="143.0" prefWidth="270.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
<children><Label text="Adobe">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
</font>
<padding>
<Insets left="10.0" top="5.0" />
</padding>
</Label><Label text="Adobe Systems,inc">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
</font>
<padding>
<Insets bottom="3.0" left="10.0" />
</padding>
</Label>
<Pane layoutX="-1.0" opacity="0.82" prefHeight="82.0" prefWidth="220.0">
<children><TextArea cache="true" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" mouseTransparent="true" pickOnBounds="false" prefHeight="82.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 0;" text="Oracle continually applies good corporate governance principles. The composition and activities of the company's Board of Directors, the approach to public disclosure" wrapText="true">
<VBox.margin>
<Insets top="53.0" />
</VBox.margin></TextArea>
</children>
</Pane>
</children></VBox>
</children>
</Pane>
</top>
<bottom>
<Pane prefHeight="45.0" prefWidth="270.0" style="-fx-background-color: white;">
<children><VBox prefHeight="55.0" prefWidth="270.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
<children><Label text="Technology">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
</font>
<padding>
<Insets left="10.0" top="4.0" />
</padding>
</Label><Label text="Software services &amp; provider">
<padding>
<Insets left="10.0" />
</padding>
<font>
<Font size="13.0" />
</font></Label>
</children></VBox>
</children>
</Pane>
</bottom></BorderPane>
</children>
</StackPane><Pane prefHeight="382.0" prefWidth="270.0">
<children><ToggleButton fx:id="toggleButton" layoutX="1.0" layoutY="191.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="30.0" prefWidth="268.0" style="-fx-background-radius: 0; -fx-background-color: #57A1DE;" text="Select profile" textFill="WHITE">
<font>
<Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
</font></ToggleButton>
</children></Pane>
</children></AnchorPane>
</children>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: Which errors you see? Maybe you need some imports? Please post the errors you get, that i can have a look how can it be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the `fx:id` attribute from the `<fx:root ...>` element, and the corresponding `profilePane` field from the Java code. These are redundant, since in the Java code the root element is simply `this`. I suspect that's just confusing your IDE.

Not relevant to your question, but you need to initialize your `FadeTransition` in the `initialize()` method, since the `toggleButton` won't have been initialized until that is called. And there is no need for the `Platform.runLater(...)` calls; the event handlers will be invoked on the FX Application Thread anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (NetBeans 8.1 with jdk8u74) was adding a fx:controller attribute to the root element of my .fxml file. For example, with root element of GridPane and controller class FXMLTableViewController in the fxmltableview package:

```
<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="fxmltableview.FXMLTableViewController">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `fx:controller="packagename.FXMLDocumentController"` class to the upper most parent in fxml document. For example, in my case I added into top `VBox` and have all components in child of `VBox`, that's why everything is working fine with me now.